# geth event newPendingTransactions does not occur

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, websocket

I've got running geth with next command:

```
$ geth --testnet --networkid 3 --verbosity 3 --syncmode light --ipcdisable --ws --wsapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,txpool,admin,miner" --wsorigins '*'
```

In second console I connect to geth jsonrpc with `wscat`.

Subscribing to an event "newHeads" **works fine**:

```
$ wscat -c ws://localhost:8546
> {"id": 2, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads"]}
< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":"0x660135584e36a9edb0c55f89c389848"}
< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_subscription","params":{"subscription":"0x660135584e36a9edb0c55f89c389848","result":{"parentHash":"0xe7d0...","hash":"0x1dcc...
```

But subscribing to an event "newPendingTransactions" **not works**:

```
$ wscat -c ws://localhost:8546
> {"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}
< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x511b3274aa5dec44bb79d178c238e7fe"}
```

And it's all: I do not get new pending transactions.

Subscribing to an event "newPendingTransactions" on ropsten.infura.io **works fine**:

```
$ wscat -c wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws
> {"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}
< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x18fda7bf20ee9c5b5f1f08edf5c3e482"}
< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_subscription","params":{"subscription":"0x18fda7bf20ee9c5b5f1f08edf5c3e482","result":"0xc1e00266ab9f2c512d6c1967c300fc00381586e868611b7dff6fd94f230dd707"}}
```

Info:

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.8.22-stable
Git Commit: 7fa3509e2eaf1a4ebc12344590e5699406690f15
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10.4
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.10
```

**I have two questions:**

**1. Why subscribing to event "newPendingTransactions" not works?**

**2. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: The problem might be that you are using a light node, since they do not have the full state they cannot validate pending transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not wait for the end of synchronization.

I started from scratch (this time i used Rinkeby network):

```
geth --rinkeby --verbosity 3 --syncmode fast --ipcdisable --ws --wsapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,txpool,admin" --wsorigins '*'
```

For the Rinkeby network, this took about 20 hours and the size of the blockchain is about 25 gigabytes on my SSD.

And now the subscribing for newPendingTransactions event **works fine**!

Thanks all!